# Raya el día en la oración "desde que raya el día hasta que sale el sol"

Tags: expresiones, significado

He encontrado esta expresión en la definición de [crepúsculo](https://dle.rae.es/crep%C3%BAsculo):

> "Claridad que hay desde que **raya el día** hasta que sale el sol, y desde que este se pone hasta que es de noche"

¿Qué significa "raya el día"?

Comment: En el diccionario de la RAE encuentras la definición numero 8 de Rayar=Amanecer. https://dle.rae.es/rayar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Rayar](https://dle.rae.es/rayar?m=form), en este contexto específico significa

> 8. intr. Amanecer, alborear. Rayar el alba, el día, la luz, el sol.

Es decir, que el crepúsculo es el periodo del día entre que empieza a haber luz (amanecer, alborear: empezar a aparecer la luz del día) hasta que empiezas a ver como sale el sol por el horizonte.

Answer (score 1):

La expresión

> rayar el día

significa "**amanecer**", lo que corresponde al "**albor**" —cuando la luz del sol aparece, **irradiando sus *rayos***. Es interesante el sentido figurado, derivable de la etimología de la palabra [***rayar***](https://definiciona.com/rayar/) que

> (...) se compone del sustantivo «raya» o «rayo» y del sufijo flexivo «ar» que indica infinitivo de los verbos, también del latín ***«radiāre» que quiere decir despedir rayos.***

En este recorte del libro [«Studia litteraria atque linguistica: N. Marín, J. Fernández-Sevilla et P. González Oblata»](https://books.google.com.ar/books?id=LWsKAQAAMAAJ&q=%22rayar+el+d%C3%ADa%22+etimologia&dq=%22rayar+el+d%C3%ADa%22+etimologia&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiw8dX-lorqAhXDDrkGHQGEAL0Q6AEIfTAJ) se puede leer una alusión al sentido metafórico de la expresión:

[image]